# How to make minimum variable sum loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a sub that basically loops through a range and adds the cell value to one of four sums (whichever is lowest), I am aware I could do this through a series of IF's but I believe it's way over-complicated and easy to mess up.

I basically have S1, S2, S3 and S4, I loop through a range of cells and let's assume:

```
S1 = 1
S2 = 3
S3 = 2
S4 = 4
```

I need the code to check the cell value and add it to the variable with the lowest sum, ie:

```
min(S1,S2,S3,S4) = min + cell value
```

for this case: S1 = S1 + cellvalue

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's over-complicating things to loop through variables with a function. Whilst an IF series may use a few more lines of code, performance-wise it is negligible.

```
Sub Test()
Dim S1 as Long, S2 as Long, S3 as Long, S4 as Long
Dim cell as Range

S1 = 1
S2 = 2
S3 = 3
S4 = 4

For Each cell in Range("A:A")    

If S4 < S3 And S4 < S2 And S4 < S1 Then
    S4 = S4 + cell.Value
ElseIf S3 < S4 And S3 < S2 And S3 < S1 Then
    S3 = S3 + cell.Value
ElseIf S2 < S4 And S2 < S3 And S2 < S1 Then
    S2 = S2 + cell.Value
ElseIf S1 < S4 And S1 < S3 And S1 < S2 Then
    S1 = S1 + cell.Value
End If

Next cell    

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked fine, just needs and adjustment for when one or several sums have same value and are all minimums. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting answers, this one does not use any ifs:

```
Sub foo()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim inptRng As Range
Dim t As Long
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("S1:S4")
Set inptRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
For Each cel In inptRng
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        t = .Match(.Min(rng), rng, 0)
        rng(t) = rng(t) + cel
    End With
Next cel

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way of finding the lowest value, assuming your data is located in Cells A1:A5

```
Sub MinMacro()


Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A5")

Dim value As Integer
value = Application.Min(rng)

msgbox value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it, but I think something like this should work:

```
[s1:s4] = [s1:s4+(s1:s4=min(s1:s4))*cellvalue]
```

Or in separate steps with temporary range for the formula results:

```
Range("z1:z4").Formula = "s1+(s1=min(s$1:s$4))*cellvalue"
Range("s1:s4").Value2 = Range("z1:z4").Value2
Range("z1:z4").ClearContents
```